# determining what authentication method/protocol I am using

Tags: security, authentication, networking, oauth, jwt

I am a beginner/noob to authentication and network security. I am completing a big academic project and part of it requires authentication of users. I was going to use auth0, OAUTH2 and all these other fancy protocols. However, I ended up generating a JWT token, storing it using localStorage, then checking if it is not equal to null  in order to grant the user access to routes that require login e.g. /home, /my_profile. Is this sufficient from a technical standpoint? What is the name of my protocol called?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not sure then it's rather not a protocol or standard. You're just using a proprietary solution, which probably means that is much less safe than using standardised solutions (like OAuth or OpenID Connect).

Btw, storing access tokens in the local storage is considered unsafe. You can have a look at [this article](https://curity.io/resources/learn/the-token-handler-pattern/) where we described the security problems of such a situation and how you can add a component which will remediate this.

Comment: Thanks for the link Michal. I will definitely get around to improving the security of my application. I guess what I am trying to ask is whether I am using a protocol at all. I am using flask-jwt-extended. The reason I want to identify the protocol is so I can name it properly during my presentation to other developers who will be assessing me

Comment: If you're not sure whether you use a standard or not, then most probably you are not ;)